# WinApi. GDI. Вывод bmp через промежуточный совместимый контекст

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi

Почему не выводит картинку код типа:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC hMemDC1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HDC hMemDC2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
SelectObject(hMemDC1, hbmp);
BitBlt(hMemDC2, 0, 0, 16 , 16 , hMemDC1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 16 , 16 , hMemDC2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

То есть через промежуточный совместимый контекст?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что, если создается контекст устройства в памяти , он вначале имеет одноцветный точечный рисунок размером 1 Х 1 пиксель, выбранный в него. Поэтому при копировании рисунка из hMemDC1 в hMemDC2 в него копируется только один пиксель.
Проблема решается созданием совместимого точечного рисунка нужного размера(в данном случае 16х16) и связыванием его с контекстом hMemDC2.

```
hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
HBITMAP btm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 16, 16);
SelectObject(hMemDC2, btm);
```